# Python map function passing multiple parameters

Tags: list, python-2.7, multiprocessing, list-comprehension, map-function

First of all I need to use map function in python and not comprehensions to implement multiprocessing.

My initial version of a list comprehension is as follows

```
t3List = [x for x in rowCost if ( cost[t1][t2]+cost[rowCost.index(x)][tour[ tour.index(rowCost.index(x)) - 1 ] ]-cost[t2][rowCost.index(x)]-cost[t1][tour[ tour.index(rowCost.index(x)) - 1 ] ]>0 and rowCost.index(x) !=t1 and rowCost.index(x) != t2 and rowCost.index(x) != tour[ tour.index(t2)+1]  and x<cost[t1][t2] ) ]
```

For more understanding `t1` and `t2` are just vertices. eg values of `t1`,`t2` are 34,21 respectively.
`rowcost` is a list which contains distances from one vertex to every other vertex.

`tour` is just some order of vertices in which I have to travel ( basically I m solving tsp )

Here all variables are local. `cost` is like just a symmetric cost matrix of all vertices.

For huge number of vertices this list is taking 0.5 to 1 sec to compute. So I planned to implement multiprocessing after seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236364/how-to-parallelize-list-comprehension-calculations-in-python)

I understood that map function takes first argument as a function.

But to implement above comprehension this function has to have multiple parameters as all the variables are local.

How to solve this problem? Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
def f(rowCost, x, cost, t1, t2, tour):
    if cost[t1][t2]+cost[rowCost.index(x)][tour[ tour.index(rowCost.index(x)) - 1 ] ]-cost[t2][rowCost.index(x)]-cost[t1][tour[ tour.index(rowCost.index(x)) - 1 ] ]>0 and rowCost.index(x) !=t1 and rowCost.index(x) != t2 and rowCost.index(x) != tour[ tour.index(t2)+1]  and x<cost[t1][t2]:
        return x
    else:
        return None

t3List = filter(None, map(f, rowCost))
```

I'm assuming that any value of `rowCost` can't value `None` in order to reduce the `map` resulto with `filter`

Comment: I don't believe this will work, because the function f takes multiple arguments and the map call only gives it rowCost to work with.

Comment: the above solution gives me a error and is completely wrong. I mentioned this in my question too that f is a function which takes only one argument i.e x

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is jabaldonedo's answer, except instead of the function `f` taking in `x, cost, t1, t2, tour` those values should be defined elsewhere and it should just reference them. i.e. your function should be "curried" from a function of many arguments into a function of one.

```
def f(rowCost):
    if <huge boolean expression>:
        return x
    else:
        return None
```