# Python multiprocessing fails for example code

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I just tried to apply multiprocessing to a loop that was written as list comprehension, as described here: [How to parallelize list-comprehension calculations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236364/how-to-parallelize-list-comprehension-calculations-in-python)

The preliminaries work as they should:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> try:
...     cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
... except NotImplementedError:
...     cpus = 2   # arbitrary default
... 
>>> 
>>> def square(n):
...     return n * n
... 
>>> pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
>>> cpus
12
```

Then, just to check, I'm not misunderstanding how `map()` works:

```
>>> map(square, range(10))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

So, that would all look reasonable so far. But when I execute the line given by Mahmoud in the accepted answer linked above:

```
>>> print pool.map(square, range(10))
Process PoolWorker-1:
Process PoolWorker-2:
Process PoolWorker-12:
Process PoolWorker-6:
Process PoolWorker-9:
Process PoolWorker-4:
Process PoolWorker-8:
Process PoolWorker-10:
Process PoolWorker-11:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.3\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'square'
Process PoolWorker-5:
```

...and this takes the entire console with it.
I've no idea why this would not work, and it seems like a very easy simple example, and 'square' is indeed defined and works, as the test with `map()` shows. Am I overlooking something so obvious that others don't even mention it? Or something version-specific?

I'm using Python 2.7.6 (Winpython 64, to be precise) on Windows 7 professional, and this happens in Spyder and in the stand-alone Python console.

Comment: here it is stated that this doesn't work in an interactive interpreter: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all the things which were wrong:

**1: Interactive console**

As user1514631 pointed out, multiprocessing [cannot run in an interactive interpreter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). This is painful for my way of programming (which involves writing half of the script in the interpreter, then pasting the correct code into a script)

**2: `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`**

This is required on Windows, otherwise I will have all CPUs generating warning messages about not using it, as soon as the worker pool is defined (way before I assign it anything to do)

**3: `if __name__ == "__main__":`**

I usually put this line in most of my code so I can use it as library or not, but this script was never going to be imported, so I did not have it.
For some reason which I have not understood, even putting the  `multiprocessing.freeze_support()` statement in the first line of a script will not work. It **must** apparently have a `if __name__ == "__main__":` line and be directly behind it, even if `multiprocessing` is only imported or used in some function.

The working code for Windows then looks like this:

```
def square(n):
    return n * n

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5)

    print pool.map(square, range(10))
```