# Parallelizing a list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, concurrency, list-comprehension

`someList = [x for x in someList if not isOlderThanXDays(x, XDays, DtToday)]`

I have this line and the function isOlderThanXDays makes some API calls causing it to take a while. I would like to perform this using multi/parrellel processing in python. The order in which the list is done doesn't matter (so asynchronous I think)

The function isOlderThanXDays essentially returns a boolean value and everything newer than is kept in the new list using List Comprehension.

Edit: 
Params of function: So the XDays is for the user to pass in lets say 60 days. and DtToday is today's date (date time object). Then I make API calls to see metaData of the file's modified date and return if it is older I return true otherwise false.

I am looking for something similar to the question below. The difference is this question for every list input there is an output, whereas mine is like filtering the list based on boolean value from the function used, so I don't know how to apply it in my scenario

[How to parallelize list-comprehension calculations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236364/how-to-parallelize-list-comprehension-calculations-in-python)

Comment: Please show us what you have done and ask a specific technical question

Comment: can you tell the isOlderThanXDays params ?

Comment: @Mars I can't show the code for the function as it's for my workplace as well as it's complex and unrelated but essentially I need to apply list comprehension based on the value being True or False. So I am filtering the new list from the old list. I have edited the question to add an example link details hope that helps.

Comment: The params aren't important here....

Comment: @rusu_ro1 Not sure if the parameters will help but I have made an edit to add parameters as well as a description of the function :)

Comment: @JayM In general, stackoverflow is for specific questions, not requests for someone to code something for you.

Comment: If there is something specific about the linked question that you don't understand, you should ask that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ThreadPool:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool # Class which supports an async version of applying functions to arguments
from functools import partial

NUMBER_CALLS_SAME_TIME = 10 # take care to avoid throttling
# Asume that isOlderThanXDays signature is isOlderThanXDays(x, XDays, DtToday)
my_api_call_func = partial(isOlderThanXDays, XDays=XDays, DtToday=DtToday)
pool = ThreadPool(NUMBER_CALLS_SAME_TIME)
responses = pool.map(my_api_call_func, someList)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I'll verify the efficiency on Tuesday when I am at work (can only access rest API on server)

Answer (score 3):

This should run all of your checks in parallel, and then filter out the ones that failed the check.

```
import multiprocessing

try:
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
except NotImplementedError:
    cpus = 2   # arbitrary default


def MyFilterFunction(x):
    if not isOlderThanXDays(x, XDays, DtToday):
        return x
    return None

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=cpus)
parallelized = pool.map(MyFilterFunction, someList)
newList = [x for x in parallelized if x]
```

Comment: Thanks heaps I should have thought of this!
 I'll test out both solutions at work on Tuesday (Can only access Rest API on their server) but for now I have marked the other one right as  my List has 25,000 - 100,000 objects. I predict checking to see if each object exists in the List may be slightly slower. I'll change the answer if this is more efficient

Comment: @JayM The answer you accepted does the exact same thing (inserts None, or assumes that `isOlderThanXDays` returns a None for you). The only benefit is that it uses `partial` which is a nice way to set XDays, DtToday.

Comment: PS, you need to set XDays and DtToday somehow too. Partial will do this for you, or you can set it yourself some other way. I just showed you how to use the code that you linked, as-is